# Xcode 6.2/Parse 1.6.4: Definition of 'PFFile' must be imported from module

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode-6.2

Today I've updated to Xcode 6.2/iOS SDK 8.2 and I've updated my project's Parse framework to 1.6.4 simultaneously. Now, I'm getting this error:

`Definition of 'PFInstallation' must be imported from module 'Parse.PFInstallation' before it is required.`

and

`Definition of 'PFFile' must be imported from module 'Parse.PFFile' before it is required.`

Both manifest as **errors**, not warnings, though interestingly my app builds.

I think modules are a Swift thing, though I'm on Objective-C and my project has nothing to do with Swift. What should I do?

**UPDATE:** Cleaning the build folder and restarting Xcode and rebuilding got me rid of the installation one, though file error is still here.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations!
You've found (yet another) bug in Xcode.
File it on bugreporter.apple.com
Cause it's still there one major release later in xcode 7.2.1
and I have to rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData all the time
to have the project build and run
(I do have swift content in the outer framework of mine though)

UPD 2016.02.18 this either seems fixed in 7.3 beta 3 OR I have strategically killed an #import somewhere which took care of this. Do not hesitate to share YOUR experience in the comments and/or answers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to import the file with framework reference like this:

```
#import <Parse/PFInstallation.h>
```